# Getting error with sscanf_s in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, input, scanf

I am trying to parse following string- `"DATA,97,103,100,97,84,69"`. This string can have following varieties-

```
"DATA,100,10,1,9,82,60"
"DATA,57,27,59,30,11,64"
"DATA,12,86,100,97,103,23"
"DATA,1,10,78,38,45,52"
"DATA,99,43,85,28,84,26"
```

Note that the first `"DATA,"` never changes. The remaining integer numbers varies from 0 to 200. Below is the code which uses `sscanf_s` function to parse these strings-

```
char ignore_data[5];
int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
char str[]="DATA,97,103,100,97,84,69";

sscanf_s(str,"%5[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", ignore_data, &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);
printf("str=%s, x1=%d, x2=%d, x3=%d, x1=%d, y2=%d, y3=%d",str, x1, x2, x3, y1, y2,y3);
```

The code does not work and shows following error

> Unhandled exception at 0x510A06E4 (msvcr110d.dll) in My Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00870000.

The above code works perfectly, when `sscanf()` is used with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` preprocessor.

I want to get the values of `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2` and `y3`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if you are able to implement the following you should be able to get the results you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ignore_data[5];
    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
    char str[] = "DATA,97,103,100,97,84,69";

    sscanf_s(str, "%5[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", ignore_data, sizeof(ignore_data), &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);
    printf("str=%s, x1=%d, x2=%d, x3=%d, x1=%d, y2=%d, y3=%d", str, x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);

    return 0;
}
```

For `sscanf_s` when taking in a string, immediately after scanning the data you will need the size of the destination buffer. This helps in making a secure port between the input stream (whatever it may be) to the destination, reducing the possibility of buffer overflow when accepting strings.

### Edit:

As *Cremno* pointed out it will need to be `sscanf_s(str, "%5[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", ignore_data, (unsigned)sizeof(ignore_data), &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);`

The attention given to the fact that the the `sizeof(ignore data)` should return an unsigned value.

Comment: Has to be `(unsigned)sizeof(ignore_data)`. See the documentation.

Comment: @Kozmik: I have not tested your code yet. Thanks a lot for your suggestion . Well, I do not want `ignore_data`, I want ONLY `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2` and `y3`. Can you tell me how to get rid of  `ignore_data` variable?

Comment: @RaviJoshi - you mean as to not read it from `str` at all? `sscanf_s(str, "%*[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);` - will not read in the first few characters up until the first `,`. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the `C11` standard, Annex K, Chapter §K.3.5.3.2,  *The `fscanf_s()` function*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `fscanf_s()` function is equivalent to `fscanf()` **except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a
>   *)**. The first of these arguments is the same as for `fscanf()`. That argument is immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument of the pair. [...]

Now, coming to the scope of `sscanf_s()`, chapter §K.3.5.3.7

> The `sscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf_s`, except that input is obtained from a string (specified by the argument `s`) rather than from a stream. [...]

Hope the above text is enough to point out the error, you're missing the second argument required for `[`, present in the format string. You need to supply the size for `ignore_data`, as `rsize_t` type.

Comment: The question is about Microsoft's `sscanf_s()`. C11 is irrelevant. However it's the same issue, just `unsigned` instead of `rsize_t`.

Comment: @cremno since when "Microsoft" started writing language? It's their implementation. So, `C11` **is** relevant. If something is non-conformal with the standard, it's not a problem with the standard, mostly it's the issue with the crappy implementation.

Comment: No, C11 is irrelevant since it didn't exist when Microsoft invented and implemented their `sscanf_s()` a decade ago.

Comment: SouravGhosh and @cremno: I really appreciate your help guys. I believe [Kozmik's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31604730/1175065) should work fine (Although I have not tested it yet). Thanks a lot.